# If I have $5^{200}$, can I rewrite it in terms of $2$'s and $3$'s to some powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have $5^{200}$, can I rewrite it in terms of $2$'s and $3$'s to some powers? For example, if I had $4^{250}$ can be written in terms of $2$'s like so: $2^{500}$.

Comment: What kind of powers? For example, is it okay by you to write $5^{200}=2^{464.385619\dots}$, or are you looking for the exponent to be an integer?

Comment: The exponent has to be an integer.

Comment: Define "in terms of".  You could write the number as a sum of powers of 2, though I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: A sum of powers of $2$ could work too.

Comment: Do you know what $5^{200}$ would be in terms of the sum of powers of $2$?

Comment: Do you know how to find the binary representation of a number?  It will be quite long.

Answer (score 4):

I think that about the best you're going to get is the binomial expansion $$\sum_{k=0}^{200}\binom{200}{k}2^k3^{200-k},$$ or something like that. The reason we can rewrite a power of $4$ as a power of $2$ is that $4=2^2$. Or, for example, $6=2\cdot 3$, so we could rewrite $$6^{200}=2^{200}\cdot 3^{200},$$ but powers of sums aren't generally very nice.

Comment: @Mike: /facepalm/ Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is the Fundamental theorem of algebra: every integer $n\geq 2$ can be written in exactly one way (up to the order of factors) as a product of powers of prime numbers.